# How to change the content of CSS node modules in Ionic react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, ionic-framework, frontend

Is there any way to change the content of CSS node modules in Ionic React? I have created some external css for my App but the css in import "@ionic/react/css/typography.css" overwrites my css. For example, I cannot change some margins, text color, etc.
I also tried to change some css inside typography.css but the changes are not loaded in the app. It's like I have changed nothing inside typography.css.
The first time I'm working with CSS in an Ionic App and I feel really confused. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic is using Shadow DOM, you can read more about it in [their blog post](https://ionicframework.com/blog/shadow-dom-in-ionic-and-why-its-awesome/). This feature is very useful to isolate components but it is also preventing you to modify the css from outside.

To fix this problem, Ionic introduced a lot of [custom CSS Variables](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables) that you can use to modify the styling of each component. This is the best way to modify the CSS of an Ionic app.

You can also read about shadow parts in [another blog post](https://ionicframework.com/blog/customize-your-ionic-framework-app-with-css-shadow-parts/) and  [he docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-shadow-parts), but this is less recommended.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have overriden the Ionic CSS Variables for example changed the primary and secondary colors of my App. If I want to add this css line : ion-button {
  --size: small;
} 
where should I add it? In variable.css doesn't work. It is not considered at all.

Comment: `--size` is actually not a css variable provided by Ionic. Try with `ion-button { --background: red; }` and you should see a difference. For size you can use the property in the html like `<ion-button size="small">`

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works with other variables except size. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Because Ionic uses Shadow Dom you can override this with CSS with some [Ionic Variables](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables#ionic-variables) like
--background and --color

```
ion-button { --background: red; }
```

But many times the changes are not reflected in all the components of the Shadow Root

To modify the css of the Shadown Root you can use the pseudo element :: part as indicated in this publication [CUSTOMIZE CSS SHADOW](https://ionicframework.com/blog/customize-your-ionic-framework-app-with-css-shadow-parts/) PARTS for example:

ion-button part is "native" so you can use

```
  ion-button::part(native){
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}
```